# C# and ReSharper: Checking an object's type

Tags: c#, interface, resharper, instanceof, implements

I have a class implementing an interface as follows:

```
public class Database : IStore
```

In another class I have the following member variable; and an instance of Database is dynamically assigned to it at run-time:

```
private IStore store;
```

and a method that does a type check on store variable as follows:

```
if (store is Database)
```

ReSharper claims the condition will always be false.  Also, it claims "store as Database" will always be null.  Why is that?  What is the best way to check the run-time object type held by this interface-type member?  Is it possibly just saying this 'may not be true' always or really that it 'never will be'?

Comment: Could you show full class that has private field store?

Comment: Comment on writing of the question: please avoid adding signature/thankyou notes. You user name is already there - no additioanl signature required (you should edit your profile if you feel that your name should be in posts), upvote/accept good answers instead of adding "thank you in advance" in your question.

Comment: Update to question: Sorry, my bad about the interface part -- it was an interface and looks like someone recently changed it to an "abstract class" so that he could stick some common methods in it.  So, IStore is now just a bad name for a public abstract class. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like either R# is confused, *or* you've got two different `IStore` types, and you're testing against one when actually the class implements a different one. (Or two different `Database` types, of course. The possibilities are equivalent.)

Are you able to produce a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem? If you hover over `IStore` and `Database` in the code with the `as` / `is` operators, does it show the fully-qualified type names you'd expect? If you run the code, *does* it ever go into the `if` body?

Comment: @pst what about my "cannot implicitly convert String to Object" experience yesterday afternoon?

Comment: @pst see my answer.  I was editing a method that passed a string constant as the argument to an indexer taking an object parameter.  ReSharper complained that the string was not implicitly convertible to object.

Comment: I've tried all these before posting, mainly because I haven't found resharper being wrong before either :-) But I don't have another IStore or Database class and when I hover over the code it points to the right classes.  I haven't tested the run-time (which I will) yet as I was making some changes to a very large project and I wanted to quickly check here if I was missing something obvious! :-)  I shall post a small repro code once I verify the run-time.

Comment: Sorry, my bad about the interface part -- it was an interface but looks like someone recently changed it to an "abstract class" so that he could implement a base method in it.

Answer (score 2):

ReSharper is obviously wrong; the question is why.  It could be resolving the types incorrectly.

Does your project compile at the moment?  Analyzing incorrect code is difficult, and our code is frequently in an incorrect state as we edit it.  I've found several cases recently of ReSharper giving similar incorrect type errors (such as "cannot implicitly convert String to Object").  After I got all the projects in the solution to compile, that went away.

Another possibility: you have a local variable `store` that is hiding the class's field `store`.  To check that, you can change your code to

```
if (this.store is Database)
```

You could also try using ReSharper's navigation to go to the declaration of `store` and of `Database`, to see if it takes you to the expected place.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that somewhere you have another class called Database. Hover over that 'is Database' and ensure it is the correct namespace. If it is not, then explicitely use the entire namespace for the Database that you want.

Answer (score 0):

In this code Resharper not say that condition always false.

```
public interface IStore
{

}

public class Database:IStore
{

}

public class TestClass
{
    private readonly IStore _store;

    public TestClass(IStore store)
    {
        _store = store;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        if(_store is Database)
            return;
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```